# If a differential operator $C$ factors as $AB$, then every solution of $C(y)=0$ has the form $y=y_1+y_2$ with $A(y_1)=0$ and $B(y_2)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

Given two constant-coefficient operators $A$ and $B$ whose characteristic polynomials have no zeros in common. Let $C = A B$. First part of question is

> Prove that every solution of the differential equation $C(y)=0$ has the form $y=y_1+y_2$, where $A(y_1)=0$ and $B(y_2)=0$.

I proved this part using the fact that they do not have zeros in common. solution of $A$ can not be a solution of $B$ and therefore $y_1$ and $y_2$ are independent for every $y_1$ and $y_2$

Second part is

> Prove that the functions $y_1$ and $y_2$ are uniquely determined. That is, there is only one pair $y_1$, $y_2$.

I don't really understand second part.

Please help me..

Comment: Are you talking about the case where $A$ and $B$ are polynomials of a single differential operator $\frac{d}{dt}$ with constant coefficients?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention characteristic polynomials for a constant coefficient differential equation, the underlying DE is linear. But then a constant multiple of a solution is again a solution, so $A(y_1)=0\implies A(ky_1)=0$ for any $k$ (and similarly for $B$ with $y_2$). So I'm not buying the uniqueness statement (at least as stated).